# This tikz-diagram has crooked arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

Consider the diagram arrows in the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  {
 A &
 B &
 \cdots &
 C 
 \\
 D &
 E &
 \cdots &
 F
 \\
  };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The arrows connected to the `\cdots` are crooked. Apparently they want to match the height of the points. But I want the arrows to flat horizontal. I use Ti*k*Z only because `amscd` does not support diagonal arrows.

How can I change the arrows to be horizontal?

Comment: Use `tikz-cd` instead.

Comment: Is your question answered by one of the posts? If not, please edit your question. If yes, please accept one answer here by clicking the check mark to its left and I will delete my comment here. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The best option here is to to switch to [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 A\arrow[r,"f"] &
 B\arrow[r,"f"] &
 \cdots\arrow[r,"f"] &
 C 
 \\
 D\arrow[r,"f"]\arrow[ur,"g"] &
 E\arrow[r,"f"]\arrow[ur,"g"] &
 \cdots\arrow[r,"f"]\arrow[ur,"g"] &
 F
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using a `matrix of math nodes`, then the problem can be prevented either using the perpendicular coordinate system  for the name nodes in the edges, as in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  {
 A &
 B &
 \cdots &
 C 
 \\
 D &
 E &
 \cdots &
 F
 \\
  };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-2.west|-m-1-1.east)
    (m-1-2.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-3.west|-m-1-1.east)
    (m-1-3.east|-m-1-1.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-4.west|-m-1-1.east)
(m-2-1.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-2.west|-m-2-1.east)
(m-2-2.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-3.west|-m-2-1.east)
(m-2-3.east|-m-2-1.east) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-4.west|-m-2-1.east)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or using  `text height` and `text depth` for your matrix nodes, as in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em,nodes={text height=1.75ex,text depth=0.25ex}]
  {
 A &
 B &
 \cdots &
 C 
 \\
 D &
 E &
 \cdots &
 F
 \\
  };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`matrix of nodes` fixes nodes alignment to `base`. This is the reason for the missalignments. You can change nodes alignment to `center` and all `edges` will be flat.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={anchor=center}, % Changes node's anchor from `base` to `center`
           row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  {
 A &
 B &
 \cdots &
 C 
 \\
 D &
 E &
 \cdots &
 F
 \\
  };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-2-4)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-3)
(m-2-3) edge node [above] {$g$} (m-1-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]